# Uncaught TypeError: recognition.addEventListener is not a function?JS speech recognition error

Tags: javascript, html, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

When i try using speech recognition im getting the error Uncaught TypeError: recognition.addEventListener is not a function,and i dont know why,i even copied code from the course that im following but it still dosnt work ,any tips will be apreciated.
Im using chrome(used webkit) and used localhost server and vscode s life server
both dosnt work

```
class SpeechRecognition{
  constructor(){}

    getSpeech(){
    //Assigning speech
    window.SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || 
     window.webkitSpeechRecognition;  

   //Speech variables
   const recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
    recognition.interimResults = true;
   recognition.lang = 'en-US';

   //UI variables
  let p = document.createElement('p');
  const note = document.querySelector('.note');
  note.appendChild(p);
  recognition.addEventListener('result', e => {

 })

}} 
 //Init 
const sp = new SpeechRecognition();
sp.getSpeech();
```

Codepen https://codepen.io/JustaJSguy/pen/zarOLW

Comment: you don't have `addEventListener` method in `SpeechRecognition` class.

Comment: How should i use it then,tips?

Comment: maybe you wanted to assign `addEventListener ` to `p` or `note` ?

Comment: I tried to aign event Listener to btn element and then tried to use one of the methods https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition but it still dosnt work

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the problem is that you named your custom class the same way as a built-in recognition class. Could you please try to rename it and check again? Also, here's a [simple implementation](https://codepen.io/pomidorcheg/pen/ZmzBXy) of Speech recognition described in the [JavaScript30 course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0mJC0A72Fnw&index=20&list=PLu8EoSxDXHP6CGK4YVJhL_VWetA865GOH).

```js
// Works in Chrome and Firefox
window.SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
// Creating new instance
const recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
recognition.interimResults = true;
recognition.lang = 'en-US';

let p = document.createElement('p');
const words = document.querySelector('.words');
words.appendChild(p);

recognition.addEventListener('result', event => {
    const transcript = Array.from(event.results)
        .map(result => result[0])
        .map(result => result.transcript)
        .join('');

    // If you make a pause,
    // you should probably create a new container for the next portion of recognized content
    if (event.results[0].isFinal) {
        p = document.createElement('p');
        words.appendChild(p);
    }

    p.textContent = transcript;
});

// We should start recognition after each pause
// Other way it will just stop recognizing forever (till the next page load)
recognition.addEventListener('end', recognition.start);

// Starting recognition first time
recognition.start();
```

```css
html {
    font-size: 10px;
}

body {
    background: #ffc600;
    font-family: 'helvetica neue';
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.words {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    padding: 1rem 2rem 1rem 5rem;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#d9eaf3), color-stop(4%, #fff)) 0 4px;
    background-size: 100% 3rem;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 3rem;
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 3rem;
}

.words:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 4px;
    top: 0;
    left: 30px;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: transparent #efe4e4;
}
```

```html
<div class="words" contenteditable>
  </div>
```

By the way, you should start recognition manually and restart it after every pause as it is shown in the snippet above.

P.S. This code will 100% work in the Chrome version 69.